# Are there any good Continuous Testing plugins for Eclipse out right now?

Tags: eclipse, testing

I've used the [MIT Continuous testing](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/pag/continuoustesting/) plugin in the past, but it has long since passed out of date and is no longer compatible with anything approaching a modern release of Eclipse.

Does anyone have a good replacement? Free, naturally, is preferred.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found that [Infinitest](http://infinitest.github.com/) now has an Eclipse plugin that seems to work pretty well.

Comment: I was trying Infinitest with Eclipse 4.3.1 and it never gets green although all tests passes using JUnit, very unfortunate for me =(

Answer (score 3):

There is a list in this Ben Rady article at Object Mentor: [Continuous Testing Explained](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2007/09/20/continuous-testing-explained).  Unfortunately the only Eclipse tool appears to be [CT-Eclipse](http://ct-eclipse.tigris.org/) which is not currently maintained either.

There is also [Fireworks](http://swing1979.googlepages.com/fireworks) for IntelliJ and [Infinitest](http://www.infinitest.org/) which is not IDE specific but also has some IntelliJ integration.

Comment: CT-Eclipse is not (from what I can tell) in active development now. Fireworks is not for Eclipse. Inifinitest works _okay_, but crashes on large projects and does not integrate with Eclipse. Thanks for the info, though.

Comment: I checked the [Infinitest repository](https://github.com/infinitest/infinitest) in github and it looks like there are a lot of open issues and few updates in the past couple years. Unfortunate :/ I'd contribute if I was worth my salt in developing Eclipse plugins

Answer (score 3):

My experience is that continuous testing within the IDE can become unwieldy and distracting, so I prefer to use something like [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) to do this kind of testing. One tool I have found very useful is [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/), which gives you a very fast coverage turnaround for your units, helping you to decide when you have finished testing a particular area of the code.

Comment: Although pointing to traditional Continuous Integration tools is certainly nice, continuous feedback in the IDE is still more frequent by at least 1 order of magnitude (I'd even say 2), so I don't feel this is really answering the question.

Answer (score 3):

Infinitest decides what tests it wants to run. Often it runs the wrong ones. Green bar sometimes good, sometimes meaningless.

Comment: I've suffered more from meaningless red bars from infinitest actually. Also, as I tend to save every couple of lines at most, infinitest ended up always running (and not often displaying results). As a result I've dropped it even though I'm convinced by continuous testing in principle...

Answer (score 1):

I've had good experience with infinitest on a small and simple project. I've not run into any issues with it and find it fast and helpful.

Comment: Just an update. Infinitest 5.x is still running great and running fine in current versions of Eclipse and Intellij

Answer (score 1):

I also use Infinitest (and voted for one of its answers), but I wanted to add another approach, which **relies on the build server**. Whenever you want to implement something, create a branch in your VCS, do your changes, commit to your branch. If you have a build server configured, which runs unit tests on every checkin, your unit tests are then run on the build server without actually having polluted the trunk (or HEAD, whatever you call it) and without you waiting for the test run to finish.

I admit that this is not really continuous unit testing in the sense you asked the question, but for large projects or large test suites even a "normal" continuous test runner may slow you down way to much.

For small projects I also recommend Infinitest or CT Eclipse.