# What are good continuous testing tools for Eclipse today (2010)

Tags: eclipse, continuous-testing

The question is in the title.

This is almost the same question, but it's dated, so I think one should not be considered a dup:

[Are there any good Continuous Testing plugins for Eclipse out right now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77090/are-there-any-good-continuous-testing-plugins-for-eclipse-out-right-now)

Comment: Where do the sun rises today? No, not necessarily the east, yesterday it rises from the east; today could be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there isn't much movement in that area, so the answers to this question are still the best we have:

[Are there any good Continuous Testing plugins for Eclipse out right now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77090/are-there-any-good-continuous-testing-plugins-for-eclipse-out-right-now)

Answer (score 0):

I find that it is generally best not to do your continuous integration tests inside your local IDE. You are much better off having an integration./automation server running Hudson, Jenkins, Cruise Control, etc. This way the tests are always done against what is in SVN, the same tests are applied to all developers code, and environmental 'weirdness' does not impact your testing. That said, it is not a bad idea to run your unit tests both locally and on the integration server. If your tests fail locally, they aren't going to work once you commit, either.

Comment: The question is about continuous testing. Not continuous integration.